# how to get random pixel index from binary image with value 1 in python?

Tags: python, random, pixel

I have a binary image of large size (2000x2000). In this image most of the pixel values are zero and some of them are 1. I need to get only 100 randomly chosen pixel coordinates with value 1 from image. I am beginner in python, so please answer.

Comment: Great. What have you tried? `PIL`  --> *Python Imaging Library* module might help you.

Comment: Also can you post the image?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest making a list of coordinates of all non-zero pixels (by checking all pixels in the image), then using `random.shuffle` on the list and taking the first 100 elements.

Comment: just a quick question - will he need to be careful about 2080 limit as mentioned here?: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Comment: A valid question.  I guess it is up to OP to decide, because we don't know what "most" in the question means - 90%? 99%? 99.99%? If there are just a few hundred non-zero pixels, it should be safe to use `random.shuffle`, otherwise it might be better to use `random.choice`.

Comment: Awesome..! Thankyou sir. I found that random.choice can not be used here as coordinates are 2 dimensional. so i have tried random.shuffle as-                        
coordinates = np.argwhere(img)
print(coordinates.shape)
index = random.shuffle(coordinates)
print(index[0:100])                                                                                               it gives me following error-TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `coordinates = np.argwhere(img)  print(coordinates.shape)  random.shuffle(coordinates) print(coordinates[0:100])`

Answer (score 1):

After importing necessary libraries like

```
import cv2
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gray_img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # grayscale

gray_img[i,j] will give pixel value at (i,j) position
```

Try to send all these values into a file in this format

```
i_positition,j_position,value_of_pixel

path = os.getcwd() + '/filename.txt'  
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, names=['i', 'j', 'value'])

positive = data[data['value'].isin([1])]  
negative = data[data['value'].isin([0])]
```

positive data frame contains all the pixel positions whose value is 1.

```
positive['i'] ,positive['j'] will give you list of (i,j) values of all the pixels whose value is 1.

i_val=np.asarray(positive['i'])

j_val=np.asarray(positive['j'])
```

Now you can randomly select any value from `i_val` & `j_val` arrays.

**Note**: Make sure that your pixel values will be 1 or 0. If your values are 0 and 255 then change this command

```
positive = data[data['value'].isin([255])]
```

Comment: Thank you..! It leads to lot of calculation. i tried np.argwhere(img) to get coordinates and random.shuffle()  to get random coordinates but i got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in sampling only 100 random coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
import numpy as np
y_idx, x_idx = np.where(image==1)   #list of all the indices with pixel value 1

for i in range(0,100):
    rand_idx = np.random.choice(x_idx)   #randomly choose any element in the x_idx list
    x = x_idx[rand_idx]
    y = y_idx[rand_idx]
    #--further code with x,y--
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another answer that might save some memory storage, or at least a for loop..

```
import numpy as np
random_image = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(2000, 2000)) > 0.5

sel_index = np.random.choice(np.argwhere(random_image.ravel()).ravel(), size=100)
random_x, random_y = np.unravel_index(sel_index, random_bin.shape)
```

I just like the usage of unravel :)